# Multiplication of cyclic permutation

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

> Find $f^{-1}gf$, where $f=(123)$, $g=(2345)$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are cyclic permutations, we have $gf=fg$. Hence
$f^{-1}gf=f^{-1}fg= (f^{-1}f)g=ig=g=(2345)$, where $i$ is identity permutation. Since i am new to this particular topic, i am not sure whether i am doing correctly?

Comment: The two cyclic permutations are not "disjoint cycles", they are not commuting. For instance, $gf(1)=g(f(1))=g(2)=3$ and $fg(1)=f(g(1))=f(1)=2$. Try first this brute force composition of functions. (First write down the inverse of $f$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that cycles commute always, **disjoint** cycles do.

So you just have to do the computation the standard way, tracing images:

$$(123)^{-1} (2345) (123)= (321)(2345)(123) = (1245)$$

Comment: I think, associativity holds in any permutation.  Doesn't it?

Comment: @gete yes, multiplication is associative so that braces don’t matter: $(ab)c=a(bc)$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

One can prove that $$\forall \sigma \in \mathfrak S_n, \ \ \sigma (i_1 ...i_m)\sigma ^{-1}=(\sigma (i_1)...\sigma (i_m)),$$
where $i_1,...,i_m\in \{1,...,n\}$ are distincts.